# Creating an editable inline textarea

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Trying to create an editable inline `textarea`. When `this.state.showTextAreaEdit` is`false` I display

```
<span>
   <textarea> {todo.title} </ textarea>
   <button> Save </button>
</span>
```

otherwise, I display:

```
 <span>
   {todo.title}
   <button onClick={this.displayEdit}> Edit </button>
 </span>
```

Demo here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-yoevt8

The problem displays nothing. There are no errors in the console.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      todos: [],
      showTextAreaEdit: false
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getTodos();
  }

  displayEdit = () => {
    this.setState({
      showTextAreaEdit: true
    })
  }

  getTodos = () => {
    axios({
      url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos',
      method: 'GET'    
    })
      .then(res => {    
        this.setState({
          todos: res.data
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.state.todos.map((todo, index) => {
          return 
            <li key={todo.id}>
              {this.state.showTextAreaEdit ?
                <span>
                  <textarea>{todo.title}</textarea>
                  <button>Save</button>
                </span> 
                :
                <span>
                  {todo.title}
                  <button onClick={this.displayEdit}>Edit</button>
                </span>
              }
            </li>
        })}
      </ul>    
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: in the demmo you have mentioned above you just nead to return the <li> item it will work i just try it. you written it in your code above but not in your demmo try it out it work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just replace your code with this one :-

what i did is that i took an new parameter on state which contain the id of selected list item and initially it is null when you click edit i pass the id on function and change its value to the id provided in the function.

and i also replace your condition. in this i check if the selected id matches the id of list item it show textarea field otherwise just simple text

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Hello from './Hello';
import './style.css';
import axios from 'axios';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      todos: [],
      showTextAreaEdit: false,
      editableTextArea:null
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getTodos();
  }

  displayEdit = (id) => {
    this.setState({
      editableTextArea: id
    })
  }

  getTodos = () => {
    axios({
      url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos',
      method: 'GET'    
    })
      .then(res => {    
        this.setState({
          todos: res.data
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.state.todos.map((todo, index) => {
        return   <li key={todo.id}>
              {this.state.editableTextArea == todo.id ?
                <span>
                  <textarea>{todo.title}</textarea>
                  <button>Save</button>
                </span> 
                :
                <span>
                  {todo.title}
                  <button onClick={()=>{this.displayEdit(todo.id)}}>Edit</button>
                </span>
              }
            </li>
        })}
      </ul>    
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

it works great within your demo  enjoy the code

Answer (score 1):

Since your return has multiple lines, you will need to wrap it in brackets:

```
{this.state.todos.map((todo, index) => {
  return ( // HERE
    <li key={todo.id}>
      {this.state.showTextAreaEdit ?
        <span>
          <textarea>{todo.title}</textarea>
          <button>Save</button>
        </span> 
      :
        <span>
          {todo.title}
          <button onClick={this.displayEdit}>Edit</button>
        </span>
      }
    </li>
  )
}
```

Comment: But when I click `edit` on one `<li> </li>` it opens to me edit textarea with all elements at once. Can you help me?

Comment: You would need to ask that as a different question since it's unrelated to your current question.

Comment: That's because you are having single state for all the elements, while you should be having different states for each of them if you want to make it work separately.

Comment: @Umbro i posted the answer check it out it solves your problem

Answer (score 1):

It's because the return statement doesn't find anything to return. Don't put enter after return statement. Try this

```
{this.state.todos.map((todo, index) => {
            return (<li key={todo.id}>
              {this.state.showTextAreaEdit ?
                <span>
                  <textarea>{todo.title}</textarea>
                  <button>Save</button>
                </span> 
                :
                <span>
                  {todo.title}
                  <button onClick={this.displayEdit}>Edit</button>
                </span>
              }
            </li>)
        })}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{this.state.todos.map((todo, index) =>
    <li key={todo.id}>
      {this.state.showTextAreaEdit ?
        <span>
          <textarea>{todo.title}</textarea>
          <button>Save</button>
        </span> 
        :
        <span>
          {todo.title}
          <button onClick={this.displayEdit}>Edit</button>
        </span>
      }
    </li>
)}
```

remove return in your map funtion at render

Comment: That won't work. The `map` needs something returned

Comment: Have you tried ? I think you should learn more about arrow function :D

const multiplyES6 = (x, y) => x * y;

x*y is the retuned value

Comment: you are absolutely right @AnhTuan it is the cleanest way to do it

Comment: @AliAsgherBadshah thank you :D unfortunately i gave 1 down vote from topic owner :<